# Flowbite-react accordion component does not work when I applied State condition?

Tags: reactjs, flowbite

when I want to show Accordion on the basis of this statement=> {access === 2 && (  <=     Screen disapppears.. and after removing this state it works.

Here is the Error and Example

Error :react.development.js:879 Uncaught Error: React.cloneElement(...): The argument must be a React element, but you passed null.                                                                                                                                                                                              Example :

```
 const [access, setAccess] = useState(null);
  setAccess(2);

 <Accordion arrowIcon="">
            <Accordion.Panel>
                <Accordion.Title >
                  dummy title 1
                </Accordion.Title>
              <Accordion.Content>
                dummy text 1.....
              </Accordion.Content>
            </Accordion.Panel>

      {access === 2 && (
            <>
              <Accordion.Panel>
                <Accordion.Title>
                  dummy title 2
                </Accordion.Title>
                <Accordion.Content>
                dummy text 2.....
              </Accordion.Content>
              </Accordion.Panel>
            </>
            )}
 </Accordion>
```

Comment: `const [access, setAccess] = useState(0);` you have to pass either 0 or 2 instead of null

Comment: it does not work even after passing 0 or 2..

Answer (score 0):

you can try using if statement before you run the code. because when the code loads it stars with null which is why it throws the error. for example

```
if(!access) return <div>loading...</div>

if(access) {
  <Accordion arrowIcon="">
        Accordion.Panel>
            <Accordion.Title >
              dummy title 1
            </Accordion.Title>
          <Accordion.Content>
            dummy text 1.....
          </Accordion.Content>
  </Accordion.Panel>

  {access === 2 && (
    <>
      <Accordion.Panel>
            <Accordion.Title>
              dummy title 2
            </Accordion.Title>
            <Accordion.Content>
            dummy text 2.....
          </Accordion.Content>
          </Accordion.Panel>
        </>
        )}
    </Accordion>
}
```